# Handling a specific runtime error in Go loop

Tags: for-loop, go, exception, panic

I'd like to catch `panic: runtime error: index out of range` in the following loop (inside function without returning) and concat `X` for each `panic: runtime error: index out of range` to the result:

```
func transform(inputString string, inputLength int) string {
    var result = ""
    for index := 0; index < inputLength; index++ {
        if string(inputString[index]) == " " {
            result = result + "%20"
        } else {
            result = result + string(inputString[index])
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

for example for `inputString = Mr Smith` and `inputLength = 10` the `result` is `Mr%20SmithXX`. It has two X because `10 - 8 = 2`.

I know I can catch the panic in returning from `transform()` but I'd like to handle it inside the loop without returning the function.

Comment: you can determine the length of `inputString` as a `[]rune` or whatever, so why have length provided externally?

Comment: Handle it by checking the length of the slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> inputString = `Mr Smith` and inputLength = `10` the result is `Mr%20SmithXX`. It has two X because 10 - 8 = 2.

---

```
package main

import "fmt"

func transform(s string, tLen int) string {
    t := make([]byte, 0, 2*tLen)
    for _, b := range []byte(s) {
        if b == ' ' {
            t = append(t, "%20"...)
        } else {
            t = append(t, b)
        }
    }
    for x := tLen - len(s); x > 0; x-- {
        t = append(t, 'X')
    }
    return string(t)
}

func main() {
    s := "Mr Smith"
    tLen := 10
    fmt.Printf("%q %d\n", s, tLen)
    t := transform(s, tLen)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", t)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/wg7MIO8yUzF

```
"Mr Smith" 10
"Mr%20SmithXX"
```